# A question considering differential calculus

Tags: calculus

I have for a very long time been thinking about certain notations in differential calculus, for instance it might sometimes be sufficient to carry out a variable substitution in integrals. For example we put $t=x^2$ and then write $\frac {dt}{dx} = 2x \Leftrightarrow dt = (2x)dx$

I dont quite understand the last step, for me, $\frac {dt}{dx}$ is just a notation for the derivative of the function $t$. What are we actually doing when we multiply each side with $dx$, I imagine that $\frac {dt}{dx}$ is just a limit when the difference in x and y tends to zero. But when we separate them then $dx=dt=0$

Does anyone understand my concerns? If not, I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 1):

To take an example, suppose you wanted to find $$\int_{x=0}^{\frac12} x(1-x^2)^3 dx.$$  How would you interpret $dx$ in that expression?

Would you be willing to do the substitution $t=x^2$ with $\frac{dt}{dx}=2x$ so that you got something like this?

$$\int_{x=0}^{\frac12} x(1-x^2)^3 dx = \int_{x=0}^{\frac12} \frac12(1-t)^3 \frac{dt}{dx} dx = \int_{t=0}^{\frac14} \frac12(1-t)^3 dt $$

Personally I regard  $dt = (2x)dx$ as shorthand for $\frac {dt}{dx} = 2x$ in a form that makes such substitutions easier to do without making errors.

Answer (score 0):

dt is the linear functional in term of dx, and it is defined as: dt = t'(x)dx = 2xdx